# Use (or not) of junction tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm in the process of developping a small project for school, and I'm unsure on a design choice.

Here is what I am trying to achieve :

I have a table of users, who are allowed to subscribe/unsubscribe from different magazines stored in a second table.

My question is fairly easy. Does that justify the use of a junction table? I was initially thinking about just including the IDs of subscribers directly in the magazine table with an additional column. It felt sloppy.

On the other hand, if I use a junction table, one way or the other I will still end up storing multiple IDs (users or magazines) into a single column, so it feels like a junction table serves no purpose.

What's your take on it?

Comment: Yes. It's a definite in cases like these. You have a list of users that describes one kind of entity. And you have a list of entities to which they can be related in a subscriber type relationship. It makes sense to describe that relationship in a third table devoted to that task/function.

Comment: Look up "database normalization", it explains the philosophy behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a many to many relationship - a student can subscribe to more than one magazine, and a magazine can have more than one subscriber.

The way to deal with this is with a junction table, otherwise you end up with duplicated data within either the student or magazine table.

Consider:

```
student
id   name   mag_id
---------------------
 1   Joe     1
 1   Joe     2
 1   Joe     3
 2   Tom     1
 etc
```

There's needless duplication of entries here in order to accommodate the M-N relationship.

A junction table is going to make things way easier in the long run:

```
student
id    name
 1    Joe
 2    Tom

magazine
id    name
 1    Weekly
 2    Sports

junction
id  stud_id    mag_id
 1     1         1
 2     1         2
etc
```

This way you have unique entries for each student-magazine pairing, less duplication of other field entries, and an easier time querying the data.

Answer (score 0):

No, the junction table would exactly avoid having multiple userids or magazineids in one row. You have two relations:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
                    userid int,
                    username text,
                    ...
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE magazines (
                    magid int,
                    magname text,
                    ...
)
```

Your junction table connects these tables (a Many-to-Many-relation):

```
CREATE TABLE user_magazine (
                    userid int,
                    magid int
)
```

Now for each abonnement make an entry in the junction table `user_magazine`. Usually you would also use foreign key constraints for the fields in user_magazine and set appropriate indices.

I would *definitively* recommend this design over your second proposed option.

Comment: For `user_magazine`, include `PRIMARY KEY(userid, magid), INDEX(magid, userid)`.

Comment: @RickJames This shall not be a complete example but show a simple table structure. Thus, I added in the text that appropriate indices have to be set. Furthermore, the primary key is automatically indexed, so your index definition is of no use.

Comment: On the contrary, my indexes are optimal for many-to-many.  It the `PRIMARY KEY` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, it is a waste, and actually slows down queries.